# Excel is asking me to update links on new files

Tags: excel

Excel has suddenly started to ask me if i want to update links even when i open a new (blank) file, what can i do? I don't believe it's my "PERSONAL", since it's been the same as before and that warning didn't show up, it's weird because if I press "Update", it sits there and says it couldn't update, and when I ask him to show me the links, it's blank.

I've looked up everywhere but I couldn't find an answer. Some guys at this forum said that it's related to the BAT file, but the thread was discontinued, so I'm lost.

Comment: are you aware of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/control-startup-message ?

Comment: well, i understand that there's the possibility of disabling warning and/or automatic update, but even if i disable it it still shows me the message if i open a new workbook